# Find a basis for the set of solutions of the given system of differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Here is what is given:
>
> $$ x' =  \begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> As the title says, we need to find a basis for the set of solutions of this differential equation.

**Here is my attempt:**

I set up this system

$$\begin{cases} x_1' = x_1 \\ x_2' = 2x_1 + x_2 \end{cases}$$

I then assumed these substitutions were made

$y = x_1$ and therefore $y' = x_2$

From this, I saw that $y'' = 2y + y'$.

Therefore:
$$y'' - y' - 2y = 0$$

I solved this characteristic equation and got these:

$$\begin{cases} y_1 = e^{-t} \\ y_2 = e^{2t} \end{cases}$$

So for my basis I got these:

$$\hat {x^1}  = \begin{bmatrix}e^{-t}\\-e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$$

And:

$$\hat {x^2} = \begin{bmatrix}e^{2t} \\ 2e^{2t} \end{bmatrix}$$

I then selected $t_0 = 0$ as a convenient value of t and then took the determinant of this matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

The determinant is equal to $3$ which means that $\hat {x^1}$ and $\hat {x^2}$ are linearly independent and therefore form a basis for the given differential equation.

However, the answer in the back of my book is different (I can post it if anyone needs it). Is my method the wrong way to approach this problem? Did I make a logical or mathematical error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As a new user, that is a well asked question. Is my edit correct?

Comment: @projectilemotion yes, thank you for the edit! My question actually looks nice now :)

Comment: You're welcome. Should the first matrix above be this instead?
$$x' =  \begin{bmatrix}1&0 \\2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$
It seems a bit inconsistent with the way you set up the system.

Comment: oh shoot, you are right, I will fix that right away

Comment: The coefficient matrix has a repeated eigenvalue and isn’t a multiple of the identity matrix, so a term of the form $ate^{bt}$ should appear somewhere in the solution.

Comment: How do you arrive at $y'=x_2$?

Comment: @amd oh I didn't know that about repeated eigenvalues, in my class we are barely going over them. I arrived at $y' = x_2$  because that is a consequence of assuming $y = x_1$

Comment: It is? Explain your reasoning in your question, since it looks to me like the place that you start going wrong.

Comment: Maybe that's where I went wrong. Sorry, I asked the same question to my TA but for a different problem where this method worked, and he said what I said, that $y' = x_2$ as a consequence of $y = x_1$, and it worked out for this other problem (I can post it if you want). I do not know why I can not do that here though...

Comment: I’d bet that in that other problem the first row of the matrix was $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}$ so that $x_1'=x_2$. The position of that $1$ makes all the difference.

Comment: @amd haha yes, that is right. Also, today my professor just taught us about eigenvalues and eigenvectors, so now I know how to solve this problem the right way :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you haven’t covered solving this system of equations directly from the matrix form yet, but I’ll offer this solution for reference.

The solution to the equation $\mathbf x'(t)=A\mathbf x(t)$ is, not surprisingly, $e^{tA}C$, where $C$ is a constant vector that depends on the initial conditions. The exponential of a matrix is defined via a power series, but there are well-known methods for computing it more directly.

We begin by finding the eigenvalues of $A=\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2&1\end{bmatrix}}$. This matrix is triangular, so we know at a glance that it has the repeated eigenvalue $\lambda=1$. Therefore, we write $A$ as the sum of a diagonal and nilpotent matrix $A=\lambda I+N=I+N$ so that $e^{tA}=e^{t(I+N)}=e^{tI}e^{tN}$. (The last equality is not true for matrix exponentials in general, but holds when the matrices commute.) For the first factor, $e^{tI}=e^tI$. For the second factor $e^{tN}$, we have $N=\small{\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\2&0\end{bmatrix}}$. $N^2=0$, which means that $e^{tN}=I+tN=\small{\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2t&1\end{bmatrix}}$. Putting the two together, $$e^{tA}=e^t\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\2t&1\end{bmatrix}$$ from which we read our basis $(e^t,2te^t)^T$ and $(0,e^t)^T$.